# The import com.google.android.maps.OverlayController cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I need some help here. I am actually following the
http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html
tutorial for learning the Driving direction on google maps but the following libraries I cant import

```
   com.google.android.maps.OverlayController;
   com.google.googlenav;
   com.google.googlenav;
```

The are giving the errors. The direction by eclipse is **The import com.google.android.maps.OverlayController cannot be resolved** 
I have set the **Google Api** emulator (means not using general emulator) and also included

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in the Menifest (Application) tab

Comment: Did you find a solution? If my question was of any help I'd suggest that you accept it. If you haven't solved the problem yet please provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, that example is from 2008. It's really old and obsolete. The most recent documentation regarding Google Maps can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Google Maps is part of the Google Play SDK and it's really easy to integrate Google Maps into your own app.

If you take a look at the comments to the forum post you linked to you'll see that people in more recent posts have problems getting this to work since the API has changed. I guess the correct way to implement it using the current Google Maps API is to use the Google Maps Directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ to get the directions from point A to B and then create an overlay using with some kind of poly line.

I think you'll find a bunch of related questions on SO if you do a search.